# Convert JSON.parse() position into line number and column

Tags: json, parsing, yarnpkg

If I have an error in my `package.json`, I see the following when running `yarn`:

> error An unexpected error occurred: ": Unexpected token } in JSON at position 333".

How do I work out what line / column number this is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### jsonlint

You can copy/paste the text into [jsonlint](https://jsonlint.com/), or install the same locally:

```
npm -g install jsonlint
```

Then see the position in the file:

```
$ jsonlint package.json
Error: Parse error on line 18:
...er": "^2.3.0"  }}}
--------------------^
Expecting 'EOF', got '}'
```

Answer (score 1):

In Vim, you can type `:goto 94` to get to the 94th character, just in front of the position 94. However this does not seem to work so well if your file contains multibyte characters.

Answer (score 0):

---

#### Using `npm` and your file is called `package.json`

Unlike `yarn`, `npm` *does* print out the context for the `package.json` error.

It's not as terse as `jsonlint`'s output, but it doesn't require an additional package.

Use `npm install` with `--dry-run` to not actually do anything:

```
$ npm i --dry-run
npm ERR! file /home/ravi/repo/erc20/pet-shop-tut/package.json
npm ERR! code EJSONPARSE
npm ERR! Failed to parse json
npm ERR! Unexpected token '}' at 18:2
npm ERR! }}
npm ERR!  ^
npm ERR! File: /home/ravi/repo/erc20/pet-shop-tut/package.json
npm ERR! Failed to parse package.json data.
npm ERR! package.json must be actual JSON, not just JavaScript.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Tell the package author to fix their package.json file. JSON.parse

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/ravi/.cache/npm/_logs/2017-10-20T09_07_12_967Z-debug.log
```